# Benchmarking two RxJava observables (Android)?

Tags: java, android, performance, performance-testing, rx-java

I have two `rx.Observable`s that do the same thing (load data from disk), but in two different ways.

```
Observable<Data> getDataFromDb();
Observable<Data> getDataFromJson();
```

I want to benchmark the performance of each, so I know which one to use. What is the best approach to do this for Android?

Answer (score 2):

Not an official benchmark, but RxJava has the `timeInterval` operator which measures the milliseconds between the arrival of subsequent values via a Scheduler's now() call (which is essentially System.currentTimeMillis() for most Schedulers). The first value will have the time difference between when the subscription happened and when the first value has been emitted.